# Using performSelectorInBackground to run loading indicator

Tags: iphone, multithreading, memory, nsthread

I have such a code:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(indicator) withObject:nil];
[self mail]; //opening my controller of e-mail sending
- (void)indicator 
{
   [actView startAnimating];
}
```

This works fine, but i'm afraid of thread safety. I'm not allocating memory in a second thread, but smth tell's me that's too simple:)

Answer (score 2):

`startAnimating` will return immediately anyway, so you don't gain anything by calling it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

you should not use this method. any UI changes from background threads will cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. It's working until the controller won't be pushed. I've added an autorelease pool to my function, for sure.